# Creating an mqtt client and subscribe with Amazon AWS Embedded C SDK

Tags: c++, c, amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I'm trying to create a simple mqtt client and subscribe to a particular topic. I need to take the payload (the received message) from the subscribe function.

The payload is a string variable that contains the following in Json Format:

```
WorkOrder Request
{"siteNumber":"client2780","testNumber":"1004","vehicle":{"make":"Dummy","model":"Vehicle","vrm":"ABC 123V","vin":"12345678901234567","vehicleClass":"4","firstRegistrationDate":"2016-12-20","fuelType":"PETROL"},"workOrderState":"COMPLETE"}
```

Unfortunately I can't use the C++ example version of the AWS SDK because I'm using RAD Studio to build my application. I'm using the Amazon Embedded C version instead to make it cross compatible with Embarcadero IDE.

This has been my attempt but is showing the client key instead of the payload string that I want when I try to show the payload:

```
     // Subscribing
    IOT_INFO("Subscribing...");
    rc = aws_iot_mqtt_subscribe(&client, "mot/in/client2780", 17, QOS0, iot_subscribe_callback_handler, NULL);
    ShowMessage(rc);
    if(SUCCESS != rc)
    {
        IOT_ERROR("Error subscribing : %d ", rc);
    }

    // Display PayLoad on screen
    paramsQOS0.payload = (void *) sPayload;       // Showing client key instead of payload string
    char * sp = &sPayload[100];
    ShowMessage(sp);
```

[image]